# Iterating on columns in dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data frames 
df1

```
+----------+----+----+----+-----+
|      WEEK|DIM1|DIM2|  T1|   T2|
+----------+----+----+----+-----+
|2016-04-02|  14|NULL|9874|  880|
|2016-04-30|  14|  FR|9875|   13|
|2017-06-10|  15| PQR|9867|57721|
+----------+----+----+----+-----+
```

df2

```
+----------+----+----+----+-----+
|      WEEK|DIM1|DIM2|  T1|   T2|
+----------+----+----+----+-----+
|2016-04-02|  14|NULL|9879|  820|
|2016-04-30|  14|  FR|9785|    9|
|2017-06-10|  15| XYZ|9967|57771|
+----------+----+----+----+-----+
```

I need to produce my output as following -

```
+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+-----+-------+-------+----------+------------+
|      WEEK|DIM1|DIM2|  T1|   T2|  T1|   T2|t1_diff|t2_diff|pr_primary|pr_reference|
+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+-----+-------+-------+----------+------------+
|2016-04-02|  14|NULL|9874|  880|9879|  820|     -5|     60|         Y|           Y|
|2017-06-10|  15| PQR|9867|57721|null| null|   null|   null|         Y|           N|
|2017-06-10|  15| XYZ|null| null|9967|57771|   null|   null|         N|           Y|
|2016-04-30|  14|  FR|9875|   13|9785|    9|     90|      4|         Y|           Y|
+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+-----+-------+-------+----------+------------+
```

Here, t1_diff is difference between left T1 and right T1, t2_diff is difference between left T2 and right T2, pr_primary is Y if row is present in df1 and not in df2 and similarly for pr_reference. 
I have generated the above with following piece of code

```
val df1 = Seq(
  ("2016-04-02", "14", "NULL", 9874, 880), ("2016-04-30", "14", "FR", 9875, 13), ("2017-06-10", "15", "PQR", 9867, 57721)
).toDF("WEEK", "DIM1", "DIM2","T1","T2")

val df2 = Seq(
  ("2016-04-02", "14", "NULL", 9879, 820), ("2016-04-30", "14", "FR", 9785, 9), ("2017-06-10", "15", "XYZ", 9967, 57771)
).toDF("WEEK", "DIM1", "DIM2","T1","T2")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val joined = df1.as("l").join(df2.as("r"), Seq("WEEK", "DIM1", "DIM2"), "fullouter")

val j1 = joined.withColumn("t1_diff",col(s"l.T1") - col(s"r.T1")).withColumn("t2_diff",col(s"l.T2") - col(s"r.T2"))
val isPresentSubstitution = udf( (x: String, y: String) => if (x == null && y == null) "N" else "Y")
j1.withColumn("pr_primary",isPresentSubstitution(col(s"l.T1"), col(s"l.T2"))).withColumn("pr_reference",isPresentSubstitution(col(s"r.T1"), col(s"r.T2"))).show
```

I want to make it generalize for any number of columns not just T1 and T2. Can someone suggest me a better way to do this ? I am running this in spark.

Comment: Could you please formulate the final question a bit clearer? Do you need to use _any number of columns_ in the expression that calculates the diff? Or do you need to be able to append _any number of columns_ like `t1_diff`?

Comment: Its both, if the number of columns are T1, T2, T3 - i want to have 3 columns - t1_diff, t2_diff and t3_diff so ideally both of them should be configurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to set any number of columns like `t1_diff` with any expresion calculating their values, we need to make some refactoring allowing to use `withColumn` in a more generic manner.

First, we need to collect the target values: the names of the target columns and the expressions that calculate their contents. This can be done with a sequence of Tuples:

```
val diffColumns = Seq(
  ("t1_diff", col("l.T1") - col("r.T1")),
  ("t2_diff", col("l.T2") - col("r.T2"))
)
// or, to make it more readable, create a dedicated "case class DiffColumn(colName: String, expression: Column)"
```

Now we can use folding to produce the joined DataFrame from `joined` and the sequence above:

```
val joinedWithDiffCols = 
  diffColumns.foldLeft(joined) { case(df, diffTuple) =>
    df.withColumn(diffTuple._1, diffTuple._2)
  }
```

`joinedWithDiffCols` contains the same data as `j1` from the question.

To append new columns, you now have to modify `diffColumns` sequence only. You can even put the calculation of `pr_primary` and `pr_reference` in this sequence (but rename the ref to `appendedColumns` in this case, to be more precise).

*Update*

To facilitate the creation of the tuples for `diffCollumns`, it also can be generalized, for example:

```
// when both column names are same:
def generateDiff(column: String): (String, Column) = generateDiff(column, column)

// when left and right column names are different:
def generateDiff(leftCol: String, rightCol: String): (String, Column) =
  (s"${leftCol}_diff", col("l." + leftCol) - col("r." + rightCol))

val diffColumns = Seq("T1", "T2").map(generateDiff)
```

*End-of-update*

Comment: Is there a way to generate diff Columns also given a Seq("T1, T2") so that Seq("T1, T2, T3" if comes would automatically gets translated to val diffColumns = Seq(
  ("t1_diff", col(s"l.T1") - col(s"r.T1")),
  ("t2_diff", col(s"l.T2") - col(s"r.T2")),
)

Comment: Yes, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the columns are named same in both `df1` and `df2`, you can do something like:

```
val diffCols = df1.columns
                  .filter(_.matches("T\\d+"))
                  .map(c => col(s"l.$c") - col(s"r.$c") as (s"${c.toLowerCase}_diff") )
```

And then use it with `joined` like:

```
joined.select( ( col("*") :+ diffCols ) :_*).show(false)
//+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+-----+-------+-------+
//|WEEK      |DIM1|DIM2|T1  |T2   |T1  |T2   |t1_diff|t2_diff|
//+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+-----+-------+-------+
//|2016-04-02|14  |NULL|9874|880  |9879|820  |-5     |60     |
//|2017-06-10|15  |PQR |9867|57721|null|null |null   |null   |
//|2017-06-10|15  |XYZ |null|null |9967|57771|null   |null   |
//|2016-04-30|14  |FR  |9875|13   |9785|9    |90     |4      |
//+----------+----+----+----+-----+----+-----+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by adding sequence number to each dataframe and later join those two dataframes based on seq number.

```
    val df3 = df1.withColumn("SeqNum", monotonicallyIncreasingId)
    val df4 = df2.withColumn("SeqNum", monotonicallyIncreasingId)

    df3.as("l").join(df4.as("r"),"SeqNum").withColumn("t1_diff",col("l.T1") - col("r.T1")).withColumn("t2_diff",col("l.T2") - col("r.T2")).drop("SeqNum").show()
```

Comment: The problem here is we are hard coding T1 and T2 while making the join between df3 and df4. If i need to do for T1, T2, T3. I will have to add withColumn again. Is there a way to place T1, T2 in a sequence, and do the computation. Similar things are needed for pr_primary, pr_reference.